# INNER JOIN creates duplicate primary key error but it shouldn't

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a new table from the inner join results of three other tables (t1, t2, t3)

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT
    t1.application_id,
    t1.text,
    t2.names,
    t2.title,
    t3.org_name, t3.project_start, t3.project_end, t3.keywords
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.application_id = t2.application_id
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.application_id = t3.application_id;
```

but keep getting a `ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '9481301' for key 'PRIMARY'`error. Each table should have id as a primary key so I'm confused why this is happening - how would one find and delete all the duplicates?

Comment: Either your query is generating duplicates or values conflict with existing values in the table.

Comment: It is about the primary key of the target table, that is `new_table`

Comment: If `new_table` has `application_id` as its primary key, you'd need to look at what your query returns, because it seems that multiple rows with the same id are returned. I would start with doing a query across all tables with `application_id = 9481301`

Comment: Have you just executed the select by itself to see its output? That should show you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your `new_table` is defined with an AUTOINCREMENT primary key.

To make your INSERT work correctly you'll need to let MySQL set that value rather than providing it from your SELECT.  Something like this may work for you.

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
     (text, names, title, org_name, project_start, project_end, keywords)
SELECT
    t1.text,
    t2.names,
    t2.title,
    t3.org_name, t3.project_start, t3.project_end, t3.keywords
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.application_id = t2.application_id
    INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.application_id = t3.application_id;
```

You do this by leaving the id value out of your SELECT, and by enumerating the columns you want to INSERT.

(This is a guess: you didn't show us your table definition.)

Comment: In mysql you can supply a value for an auto_increment column.

Comment: You sure can supply values for autoincrement columns, but if you do they better not be  duplicates, or you get the OP's error.